# Deserialize xml element string

Tags: c#, xml, string, deserialization

I have this XML element string:

```
<person name="jhon smith" birth="11/10/1988" username="ilearn" password="123"/>
```

Now I want to deserialize this to its respective object:

```
public class CancelCardResponse
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string birth { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using a code similar to this:

```
XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));
StringReader reader = new StringReader(myxmlelementstring);

var a = deserializer.Deserialize(reader); // fail!
```

The error says something like:

> **System.InvalidOperationException** {"**There is an error in XML document
>   (1,2).**"}

Is it possible to derserialize an XML element string like the one above?

Is there something I can add to my XML element string to use the C# deserializer?

Comment: Was this xml serialized by .NET?

Comment: also, why is the class called `CancelCardResponse` instead of `Person` as in your code?

Comment: you need to add attributes to your class and properties to map them to the XML doc schema.

Comment: This is an xml string that I get from a webservice

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
public class person
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string birth { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string username { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string password { get; set; }
}
```

I didn't compile or test it, and it's been a little while since I've user `XmlSerializer` but this should get you there or close to it.

Answer (score 0):

Rename your `CancelCardResponse` class to `Person` and annotate it's properties with `[XmlAttribute("Attr Name as in XML")]`